# Does config file sku specify a single exact or the minimum .NET Framework required?

Tags: .net, deployment, app-config

Does specifying the 'sku' in an app.config file indicate that the exact .NET Framework version is required or that this version or higher is required?

e.g., the config file contains (for an application targeting .NET Framework 4.5):

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
```

On a machine with only version 4.6 installed, will this be a problem?